# React Table column filter issue when the page render

Tags: reactjs

I am using react table for my project. I am trying to add column filter for my project. please check my table header code

```
        <thead>
      {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
          {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
            <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
              {column.render("Header")}
              <span>
                {column.isSorted
                  ? column.isSortedDesc
                    ? " "
                    : " "
                  : ""}
              </span>
              <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render("Filter") : null}</div>
            </th>
          ))}
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </thead>
```

This is my column.js file

```
    import React from "react";

export const ColumnFilter = ({ column }) => {
  const { filterValue, setFilter } = column;
  return (
    <span>
      <input
        value={filterValue || ""}
        onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)}
      />
    </span>
  );
};
```

after I added filters to my table column. this is the one header that I added.

```
  {
Header: "Type",
accessor: "INVOICE_LINE_ID",
Filter: ColumnFilter,
```

},

I think I added every thing correctly. but error occurred. According to error, error came from the
"{column.canFilter ? column.render("Filter") : null}" this line.

But i could not find the error.[Error preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJhEQ.png)
If i comment that line, project is working well and sorting, paganing and everything working.
how can i fix this issue

Comment: It will be hard to help without the full code, you don't show us the actual bugged function here (`.render` method of your column)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
In the [docs example](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/filtering), it has been specified that

> you need to pass the default column option to useTable hook

Hence in your Table Header component, eg FilteringTable.js

1. Define defaultColumn component that uses useMemo hook

FilteringTable.js

```js
import { ColumnFilter } from './ColumnFilter'

const FilteringTable = () => {

  const columns = useMemo(()=> GROUPED_COLUMNS, [])
  const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, [])
  
  const defaultColumn = useMemo(
    () => ({
      // Let's set up our default Filter UI
      Filter: ColumnFilter,
    }),
    []
  )  
}
```

2. Pass the defaultColumn option to useTable hook

FilteringTable.js

```js
import { ColumnFilter } from './ColumnFilter'

const FilteringTable = () => {

  const columns = useMemo(()=> GROUPED_COLUMNS, [])
  const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, [])
  
  const defaultColumn = useMemo(
    () => ({
      // Let's set up our default Filter UI
      Filter: ColumnFilter,
    }),
    []
  )  
  
    const { 
    getTableProps, 
    getTableBodyProps, 
    headerGroups,
    footerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    setGlobalFilter,
  } = useTable({
    columns: columns,
    data: data,
    defaultColumn // Be sure to pass the defaultColumn option
  },
  useFilters,
  useGlobalFilter)
}
```